# Discord bot doesn´t connect

Tags: python, django, discord, bots, discord.py

I have created this little sample code for a discord bot, but when I try to connect I get the following error.

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import urllib.request
import json

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='¿')  # prefix del bot


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="Tutorial", url="http://www.twitch.tv/palmart69"))
    print('bot listo')


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong!")


@bot.command(name='suma')
async def sumar(ctx, num1, num2):
    response = int(num1) + int(num2)
    await ctx.send(response)


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

```py
--------ERROR------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\PycharmProjects\bot-pruebas\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1081, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1111, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 528, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 188, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1123)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\PycharmProjects\bot-pruebas\main.py", line 31, in <module>
    bot.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\PycharmProjects\bot-pruebas\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 718, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\PycharmProjects\bot-pruebas\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 697, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\PycharmProjects\bot-pruebas\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 660, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\PycharmProjects\bot-pruebas\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 509, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\PycharmProjects\bot-pruebas\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 293, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\PycharmProjects\bot-pruebas\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\PycharmProjects\bot-pruebas\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\PycharmProjects\bot-pruebas\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\PycharmProjects\bot-pruebas\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\PycharmProjects\bot-pruebas\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\PycharmProjects\bot-pruebas\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\PycharmProjects\bot-pruebas\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Alvaro\PycharmProjects\bot-pruebas\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 971, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1123)')]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

I have tried several things that I have seen on different posts (such as installing certificate). I´m new to this bot world so I would really appreciate a bit of help with this. Thanks before anything.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve finally solved the problem with [this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/4159#issuecomment-640274951)(downloading a new certificate and installing it).